# os.popen to subprocess conversion using pytest

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, pytest, hashicorp-vault

I was using os.popen() before to run my tests with pytest and everything was working. All of my tests are related to writing, modifying or deleting in Vault. The issue is one of my tests requires me to get a return code value, which isn't available with os.popen() so I've made the switch to subprocess() but now I can't seem to get any of the functions working.

I've been going through the doc and what I've noticed is instead of being able to just pass a string like os.popen did I need to add another parameter but anything I add doesn't work.

This code use to work before I had to switch to subprocess:

```
command = os.popen('vault write test/Hello value=world')
print(command.read())
```

Here is an example of one of my tests that fails now:

```
# Add secret and verify in vault
    def test_add_secret_and_verify(self):
        try:
            command = subprocess.run('vault write test/Hello value=world')
            print(command.read())
            print("Secret created!")

            command = subprocess.run('vault read -field=value test/Hello')
            result = command.read()
            print(result)
            print("Verifying secret - "+result+" - is the same as created!")

            self.assertEqual(result, "world")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            self.fail()
```

There are multiple pages of errors but in the end it just fails and says subprocess.run() doesn't work. Does anyone have an idea of what I could change to get this function to work or maybe recommend if I should be using another function?

Comment: Not familiar with `vault`, is `vault write test/Hello value=world'` a single command?  Try `command = subprocess.run(['vault', 'write', 'test/Hello' 'value=world'])`

Comment: Would something like this work? `print(subprocess.check_output("echo 'success'", stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True))`

Comment: @cdarke Vault is a tool used to store tokens and secrets, and yes that is a single command. Im creating a secret called 'Hello' in the folder 'test' with a value of 'world'

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the args argument which subprocess.run takes should be a list of strings. So you need to run it like:

```
result = subprocess.run(['vault', 'write', 'test/Hello', 'value=world'])
```

or

```
result = subprocess.run('vault write test/Hello value=world'.split(" "))
```

You can read more about the subprocess module [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

Comment: Thanks it seems to work for the first command to write but there seems to be no output when I do a read. So I set the value of the secret 'world' and when I try to read the value it says it's 'world' but if I put that read command into a variable and try to print the value it says the value is none. I did a ```print(result.stdout)``` but received a result of 'none' even though I know it's 'world'.

Before I would do ```result.read()``` and it would output 'world' not 'none'
Is there no way to check that the output and get the actual value?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help! I just want to print out the answer to the first command that Markus helped me with and the 2nd command that I was able to figure out.

`command = subprocess.run('vault write test/Hello value=world'.split(" "))`

Did end up working and created a value of 'world'

`result = subprocess.run('vault read -field=value test/Hello'.split(" "),stdout=subprocess.PIPE,universal_newlines=True)`

it ends up adding the value into a string

`self.assertEqual(result.stdout, "world")`

Finally the equal function works because the output of result is world and its equal to the word I've set.